# How to use CMake in NetBeans to build programs?

Tags: c++, macos, netbeans, cmake

I've been using NetBeans for a while for my C++ projects. I previously used only make but not cmake. Some colleagues then requested that my codes be compiled using cmake to be "cross-platform"

However, I am having a hard time to set up the NetBeans project using a cmake on OS X. Either it complains that cmake is not found, or does not show the files correctly and completely. Also, cmake seems to be creating some mess in my project directory. Any idea on how to set them up?